# Notify caller that a thread has finished

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to use the multithreading features in the C++11 standard library and have the following situation envisioned.

I have a parent class which maintains a queue of thread. So something like:

```
std::queue<MyMTObject *>  _my_threads;
```

The class `MyMTObject` contains the `std::thread` object.
The queue has a fixed size of 5 and the class initially starts with the queue being full.

As I have jobs to process I launch threads and I remove them from the queue. What I would like is to get a notification when the job is finished along with the pointer to the `MyMTObject`, so that I can reinsert them into the queue and make them available again.

I have basically 2 questions:

1: Is this a sound idea? I know I have not specified specifics but broadly speaking. I will, of course, control all access to the queue with a mutex.

2: Is there a way to implement this notification mechanism without using external libraries like `Qt` or `boost`.

For duplicates, I did look on the site but could not find anything that was suitable to manage a collection of threads.

Comment: I do not think the duplicate is correct. The question is about single thread, OP has a collection of them.

Comment: I agree. I think this is one of the many cases where the *answers* would be close to duplicates, but the question is not at all.

Comment: You could pass a callback to the thread when you initialize it, and then invoke the callback just before terminating the thread. Not the most beautiful solution, but it should work.

Comment: Are your threads detached?

Comment: @jweyrich This seems like a reasonably low cost approach. Wanna write it as an answer? I will give it a shot.

Comment: @Jason The threads do not have to communicate with each other.

Comment: What does that have to do with being detached?

Comment: @Jason If you mean my thread is separate from the `MyMtObject`, than no. The threads needs access to data private to `MyMtObject`. I am afraid I probably do not understand what a detached thread is.

Comment: What I mean is if you've called `std::thread::detach`.

Comment: @Jason No, I have not.

Comment: You could use a custom deleter. Instead of storing the raw pointer in the queue, you use a smart pointer that reinserts into the queue on deletion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I need to mention this, but `std::thread` objects can't be re-used.  Generally, the only reason you keep a `std::thread` reference is to [`std::thread::join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) the thread.  If you don't plan to join the thread later (e.g. dispatch to threads and wait for completion), it's generally advised to [`std::thread::detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) it.

If you're trying to keep threads for a thread pool, it's probably easier to have each thread block on the `std::queue` and pull objects from the queue to work on.  This is relatively easy to implement using a [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).  It generally gives good throughput, but to get finer control over scheduling you can do things like keep a seperate `std::queue` for each thread.

Detaching the threads and creating a work queue also has the added benefit that it avoids redundantly requesting the operating system create new threads which adds overhead and increases overall resource usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to deploy some version of [Reactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) I think. So, you could start one additional **control** thread that *cleans* after these workers. Now, you create a `ThreadSafeQueue` that will be used to communicate events from worker threads to control thread. This queue should be implemented in such a way that you can `select` on it and wait for any activity on the other end (some thread terminates and calls `queue.push` for example).

All in all I think it's quite elegant solution. I does add an overhead of an additional thread, but this thread will be mostly sleeping and waking up only once a while to *clean up* after the worker.

Answer (score 0):

There is no elegant way to do this in Posix, and C++ threading model is almost a thin wrapper on Posix.

You can join a specific thread (one at a time), or you can wait on futures - again, one future at a time.

The best you can do to avoid looping is to employ a conditional variable, and make all threads singal on it (as well as indicating which one just exited by setting some sort of per-thread flag) just before they are about to exit. The 'reaper' would notice the signal and check the flags.

The issue is that this solution requires thread cooperation. But I know not of any better.